# Sandbox account for paypal when paid using credit/debit card shows error

Tags: android, paypal

This is the error

```
request failed with server response:{"name":"DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","message":"PayPal-Request-Id header was already used.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","debug_id":"848e3db5def20"}
```

How to overcome this issue? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: please explain your issue with snap code, which method have been used for payment

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you retried the transactions after it failed the first time. If you haven't done that, then other possibility is that paypal internal system retried on an error and this error was thrown. Anyway the reason of the error for you seems to be that you are using an indian merchant and an indian buyer which is not supported. Try creating a merchant with a different country for Direct Credit Card payments. And i assume you are using sandbox so it is possible for you to create another merchant.

Comment: Sandbox credit card details is not working and is showing this error. When I have used another dummy card detail it worked.